Code not pushing into a private repository
Authentication failed.
enter image description here
I just changed my laptop and i've added my info but its not allowing me to push to a private repository.
I've tried logging in and logging out, I've also removed myself from the project and adding myself back but to no avail.

Please share more details, like the error message in text form. Also, are you sure your problem is in any way related to [tag:code-collaborator]?

Please do the following,

Update Credentials: Run the following command:
git config --global credential.helper cache
Then, try pushing to prompt for credentials.

Use Personal Access Token (PAT):If using HTTPS, generate a PAT on GitHub and use it instead of a password.

Check SSH Key: If using SSH, ensure your SSH key is added to your GitHub account. Test with:
ssh -T git@github.com

Verify Remote URL: Check your remote URL with:
git remote -v


